# Performant 2D plotting

Tags: qt, plot, 2d, heap-memory, visualization

I am looking for plotting library (using Qt as UI currently), but my problem is as follows: I need to draw **millions** of very small rectangles on canvas and be able to zoom canvas in and out. The requirements: it has to be very fast, preferably cross-platform. With "fast" I mean plotting couple of millions (or more) rectangles in under a second.

Everything I tried so far was too slow. I have been using Qt+OpenGL, but it is bit too low-level, and was slow anyway (probably due to lack of experience in OpenGL). Also qcustomplot, unfortunately too sluggish. Even tried HTML+Canvas as an experiment.

For those wondering why I have such requirements and to better understand what I need, please see this presentation: [Heap Visualisation Tools](https://www.area41.io/downloads/slides/thomas_dullien_heap_visualisation_tools.pdf) (see slides 10 to 17, and 28-29).

What are your suggestions? What tool/library/framework can be capable of drawing several millions of rectangles without noticeable performance issues? I could even use web if there is some fast enough JavaScript library. Maybe something using the LOD under the hood.

Comment: Go back and take the time to learn more OpenGL. How slow was your OpenGL code? Is your list of rectangles changing every second (?!?), or do you just need to create the 3D graphic in one second and then allow the user to scroll and zoom in and out for as long as they'd like? (If you're creating a zooming user interface in which a user can zoom in to any one rectangle within the context of millions, you're going to run into some UI/UX problems that are fun to solve.) Together, "fast" and "graphics" and "zoom" should lead you to OpenGL running in retained mode on a discrete graphics card.

Comment: On a modern GPU, you should be able to plot these rectangles at 60FPS, pretty much, and the code should fit in what - a 150 lines? Perhaps I should demonstrate that, it's not supposed to be hard at all, and you're supposed to abstract out anything "low" level anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: You should be able to draw ~10 million small rectangles in one second on a 4 core system, using nothing but `QPainter::drawRect` on a `QImage`.

Drawing a million rectangles isn't a big deal, a typical 1920x1080 screen has about 2 million pixels, so drawing "small" rectangles is like writing each pair of pixels individually, or writing 8 bytes per rectangle, on average.

On my particular system, an i5 iMac running Qt 5.6, it takes ~1/3s to draw 1 million small rectangles:

```
#include <QtWidgets>
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QApplication app{argc, argv};
  QImage image(1920, 1080, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
  QPainter p(&image);
  QElapsedTimer timer;
  timer.start();
  int n = 0;
  for (int y = 0; y < image.height(); ++y)
    for (int x = 0; x < image.width(); x+=2) {
      ++ n;
      p.drawRect(x, y, 2, 1);
    }
  p.end();
  qDebug() << n << timer.elapsed();
}
```

If you wish, you can parallelize the drawing across several threads.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/qimage-rectangles-37510435
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtConcurrent>

QVector<QRect> rects(const QSize & size) {
  QVector<QRect> rs;
  for (int y = 0; y < size.height(); ++y)
    for (int x = 0; x < size.width(); x+=2)
      rs.append(QRect(x, y, 2, 1));
  return rs;
}

QImage render(const QVector<QRect> & rects, const QSize & size, const QPair<int,int> range)
{
  QImage image(size, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
  image.fill(Qt::transparent);
  QPainter p(&image);
  QElapsedTimer timer;
  timer.start();
  const int n = range.second-range.first;
  for (int i = range.first; i < range.second; ++i)
    p.drawRect(rects[i]);
  p.end();
  qDebug() << n << timer.elapsed();
  return image;
}

struct Render {
  const QVector<QRect> & rects;
  const QSize & size;
  typedef QImage result_type;
  QImage operator()(const QPair<int,int> range) { return render(rects, size, range); }
  Render(QVector<QRect>& rects, const QSize& size) : rects(rects), size(size) {}
};

template <typename Seq>
QVector<QPair<int,int>> partition(const Seq & s, int n)
{
  QVector<QPair<int,int>> ps;
  ps.reserve(n);
  int begin = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    int end = (s.count() * (i+1))/n;
    ps.append(qMakePair(begin, end));
    begin = end;
  }
  return ps;
}

void combine(QImage & result, const QImage & source)
{
  if (result.isNull()) {
    result = source;
    return;
  }
  QPainter p(&result);
  p.drawImage(0, 0, source);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QApplication app{argc, argv};
  QSize size{1920, 1080};
  auto rs = rects(size);
  auto ranges = partition(rs, QThread::idealThreadCount());
  QElapsedTimer t;
  t.start();
  QtConcurrent::blockingMappedReduced(ranges, Render(rs, size), combine);
  qDebug() << "parallel time" << t.elapsed() << "ms";
  t.restart();
  render(rs, size, qMakePair(0, rs.count()));
  qDebug() << "serial time" << t.elapsed() << "ms";
}
```

Output:

```
259200 94
259200 97
259200 102
259200 102
parallel time 112 ms
1036800 360
serial time 362 ms
```

If you could group the rectangles into groups that have same pen/brush, then do leverage the fact that `drawRects` is faster than repeated calling of `drawRect` (~20% faster on my machine).

You could also implement a non-transformed `drawRect` yourself and make it even faster.

Comment: I have tested it in real application, 1.8M rects are serially rendered in 7 seconds on my hardware (dedicated GPU, 6 core CPU), using drawRects.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that 7 seconds in Debug mode, Release mode in about 2 seconds. But still not enough, thinking of some optimizations.

Comment: @unsigned It takes 2 seconds spread across 6 cores or just on one core? On what format of `QImage` (it can make a *huge* difference). Also note that these rects are way too small to see, so by the time the user has zoomed in, it'll be much faster even if you let `QPainter` do all the clipping for you. For raster paint engine on a `QImage`, the GPU doesn't matter at all. It literally does nothing.

Comment: Just one core takes 2 seconds, QImage Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied, (I also tried QPixmap, but it is not faster.) The problem is that I can make use of several cores, but software users may have less cores.

Comment: `QPixmap` on the default raster backend is really internally just a `QImage` in a certain format, so it won't help and makes no difference here.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not really "scale". If I want to draw bit larger rectangles, then it is unusable even if I compute across cores. Good solution for lesser amount of objects though.

Comment: @unsigned The rectangles must not overlap and must be at least a pixel across. You can not get more examples than visible pixels. You're not telling us something.

Comment: I have managed to reduce number of rectangles to draw (by implementing something similar to LOD, don't know how it is caller correctly), and performance is much better now. Also I have read here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#performance that it is possible to use OpenGL as a backend for QPainter. Does it means that QPainter methods will use OpenGL or it means that I need to mix OpenGL methods with QPainter anyway? I just want to move as much as possible of operations to GPU if I use QPainter (w/o using OpenGL itself).

Comment: Just FYI, I am running tests with QGraphicsView and it seems to be much faster than QPainter (according to book I am reading it is supposed to be).

Comment: @unsigned Only if you're seeing only a small subset of the rectangles at a time. `QGraphicsView` uses `QPainter` and the default raster backend, it only adds some overhead on top of it. For a situation with millions of *visible* rectangles, it will slow you down. For a situation with just a couple thousand visible out of millions, it'll be faster. You can also try painting directly on a `QOpenGLWidget` via `QPainter`, but you should bunch operations on the same state via `drawRects`.

Comment: Currently rendering 70k rectangles (effectively lines w/o zoom) with QGraphicsView in ~0.23 seconds (0.1 sec for function filtering of 1.2M blocks), better than any other method I tried (except of OpenGL), but seems that I will have to stay with OpenGL anyway (I made some corrections, now it is way faster). Btw, as far as I understand  `this->setViewport(new QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::DirectRendering)));` makes QGraphicsView to use OpenGL backend?

Comment: @unsigned It does, but using OpenGL directly may be even faster.